# Drupal 6 site updates are not been applied

Tags: 6, updating

I have a Drupal 6 site running fine, but when trying to apply updates to its modules by uploading the latest version of the module and visiting update.php the update process complete, but when I check the available updates report it still show me the old module versions marking them as outdate.

I can read and write in the DB, and I can upload files to the server so it is not a DB  or file permission.

Can you explain why the updates are not being applied/seen?

Comment: Does update.php show updates that are going to be applied?

Comment: No, in the list of modules none of them show that the module will be update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to put this here in case someone else has the same issue.

The problem was in my case the I was backing up the old modules folders to a folder call "old backup" in /site/all/modules/ so that in case something goes wrong I can just grap the old copy while I figure out what was wrong.

The problem was that the site module scanner was grabbing in the old modules new location and that is why I was never able to apply the updates.

I was able to tell using the comments above about checking the DB.

When I check the system table I notice this:

sites/all/modules/old backup/ctools/ctools.module

instead of this:

sites/all/modules/ctools/ctools.module

Thank you all for your ideas as they help me figure out what was wrong and I hope this can help some one else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you clear the cache?

Are you sure you are updating the right modules? Drush for example will place modules in sites/all/modules, but if your modules are placed in profiles/profile/modules Drupal might still be reading the old modules.
Drupal won't complain if you are having duplicates, only on enabling.

Can you confirm the modules are read? Check the database, are the module path correct? Is the info file of you modules showing the correct version?

Answer (score 1):

As an additional precaution: are you overriding the existing module files with the new ones? If so, I'd try deleting the module to be updated first and then uncompressing the new one.

Comment: I did both without luck

Comment: This is going to look silly, but it has happened to me more than once. Are you sure you are uploading in the right folder? When I make significant changes to a site I usually clone it into another folder that has a slightly different name.